# Libgdx Fog of War (Texture blending), Framebuffer bug

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx, blending

i try to get a simple fog of war for my strategy game.

I fail at the moment on framebuffer drawing.
Im an absolute openGL beginner.

New Problem 1;

Contructor:

```
    int width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    int height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    this.fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, width, height, false);
    this.fboRegion = new TextureRegion(fbo.getColorBufferTexture(), 0, 0, 1000, 1000); // 1000,1000 = Test mapsize

    fboRegion.flip(false, true);

    Units.camera.setCam(new OrthographicCamera(fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight()));
    OrthographicCamera cam = Units.camera.getCam();
    cam.position.set(fbo.getWidth() / 2, fbo.getWidth() / 2, 0);
    cam.update();
```

Render part:

```
public void draw(float delta)
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Units.camera().update();

    fbo.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(Units.camera().getCam().combined);

        batch.begin();

            background.draw(batch);
            this.unitDraw.draw(batch, delta);
            this.shotDraw.draw(batch, delta);

        batch.end();
    fbo.end();


    batch.begin();
        batch.draw(fboRegion, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Problem:
The camera move wrong. The framebuffer and the textureregion move different speed.
My objects have a low resolution on the texture region because its scaling. But i need scaling my object pictures. How increase the resolution without scaling images to original size ? Scaling Batch before write in framebuffer ? or is this a camera problem ?

**See:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMGe1Sgh5JA&feature=youtu.be

The last post in this thread (http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4207) has the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean fog?  Fog of war is a psychological effect, not a visible one.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede you are wrong,"Fog of war" is term used in RTS games to describe visual effect of  uncovering hidden areas of the map.

Comment: @MichaelIV That seems to trivialize the experience...

Comment: Have edit my problems. Image http://i.stack.imgur.com/g0ODg.png. Have double background texture bug. First background texture is drawing perfect but the second one draw transparent. Why there are two background textures?

Comment: It's impossible to know what's wrong in those pictures without knowing what it's supposed to look like or without you describing exactly what's wrong with it.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Isn't fog of war the lack of knowledge about one's circumstances/surroundings when involved in a war? The RTS version of fog of war is an almost perfectly analogous visualization of the term.

Comment: Have edit my description. Have now a video for you.